# Want to re-instantiate a component when navigating to same aux route

Tags: angular2-routing

I have a list of items with Actions drop-down for each item in the left-section of page. I also have a right rail which displays a different component based on action type selected. I'm using aux-route to accomplish this.

One of the Action the user can take is "edit" where in a form is displayed to edit the metadata of the list item. While editing, user can click on + button next to some of the input field to add another input field dynamically.

Now my problem is, when the edit-form is open for a list item and I click edit on another item in the list, I wanted my edit-component to be re-instantiated.

Because the aux-route is same for all the list items for edit-action, edit-view is not instantiated once again. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Right now fixed it with RouteReuseStrategy